# Parse JSON data inside a Complex loop using SimpleHtmlDom

Tags: php, json, simple-html-dom

I want to display the contents of a json script with the help of `simple HTML Dom` and my goal is to display the second `"@type": "user"` name and url feed:

my Json :

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
              
              "type": {
                "@type": "Type",
                "name": "admin"
              },
              "offers": {
                "@type": "AggregateOffer",
                "offerCount": "30"
                ,"offers": [
            {
              "@type": "user",
            "name": "abc",
            "url": "https://test.com",
            },{
                "@type": "user",
            "name": "eds",
            "url": "https://example.com",
            },{
                "@type": "user",
            "name": "gfh",
            "url": "https://test.com",
            },{
                "@type": "user",
            "name": "dfc",
            "url": "https://test.com",
            },
            .
            .
            .
```

My desired output:
"name": "eds",
"url": "https://example.com"

For this I am using following code:

```
$json = $html->find('script[type="application/ld+json"]',0);
echo $json->innertext;
```

But this code shows me all the json contents, I really don't know how to make a condition in my code that only the second `"@type": "user"` name and url feed from this complex cycle will be displayed to me

Comment: Well you need to _decode_ the JSON, and then access the elements you are interested in, in the resulting data structure ... (What you have shown above is not valid JSON though.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML and JSON are valid:

```
$html = '
<body>
<h1>hello </h1>
<script type="application/ld+json">{
    "type": {
        "@type": "Type",
        "name": "admin"
    },
    "offers": {
        "@type": "AggregateOffer",
        "offerCount": "30"
        ,"offers": [
            {
            "@type": "user",
            "name": "abc",
            "url": "https://test.com"
            },{
            "@type": "user",
            "name": "eds",
            "url": "https://example.com"
            },{
            "@type": "user",
            "name": "gfh",
            "url": "https://test.com"
            },{
            "@type": "user",
            "name": "dfc",
            "url": "https://test.com"
            }
        ]
    }
}   
</script>';

$dom = new DomDocument(); 
$dom->loadHTML($html); 
$node= $dom->getElementsByTagName("script")[1];
$text= $node->textContent;
$obj = json_decode($text, true);
echo $obj["offers"]["offers"][1]["name"];
echo $obj["offers"]["offers"][1]["url"];
```

UPDATE: There are other errors in the page that prevent the parser from working. I suggest using a function to extract the script tag text.

```
function after($this1, $inthat)
{
    if (!is_bool(strpos($inthat, $this1))) {
        return substr($inthat, strpos($inthat, $this1) + strlen($this1));
    }
    return null;
}

function before($this1, $inthat)
{
    return substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $this1));
}

function between($this1, $that, $inthat)
{
    return before($that, after($this1, $inthat));
}

$text = between('<script type="application/ld+json">', '</script>', $html);
// then continue like before.
```

Comment: it returns this error  `Cannot use object of type simple_html_dom_node as array` and `Trying to get property 'textContent' of non-object`

Comment: my test page is [link](https://torob.com/p/ee208982-b38f-456a-bd2c-7d622a5a9156/%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%B4%DB%8C-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%86%DA%AF-a52s-5g-%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B8%D9%87-128-%D8%B1%D9%85-8-%DA%AF%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA/)

Comment: I changed a little, having seen the page, the `<script>` tag is the 2nd one, and indeed JSON inside is valid.

Comment: I changed this to 2 myself, but it gave me an error, I also applied the change you gave, but it shows me this error: `Trying to get property 'textContent' of non-object` in line: `$text= $node->textContent;`

Comment: Do you have a solution to fix this error? @it-goldman

Comment: Yes I have already edited my answer

Comment: this my code: `$html = file_get_html($url);

 $text = between('<script type="application/ld+json">', '</script>', $html);
 $dom = new DomDocument(); 
 $dom->loadHTML($html); 
 $node= $dom->getElementsByTagName("script")[1];
 $text= $node->textContent;
 $obj = json_decode($text, true);
 echo $obj["offers"]["offers"][1]["name"];
 echo $obj["offers"]["offers"][1]["url"];`  but it returns this error: `DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag svg invalid in Entity` and $url is the page address.

Comment: It could be that the relevant `<script>` tag is not the second one on the page\

Comment: my test page is [link](https://torob.com/p/ee208982-b38f-456a-bd2c-7d622a5a9156/%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%B4%DB%8C-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%86%DA%AF-a52s-5g-%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B8%D9%87-128-%D8%B1%D9%85-8-%DA%AF%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA/) and error is a bout svg tag